# Read file from ClipData in OnDragListener

Tags: java, android, file, drag-and-drop, uri

I'm trying to implement drag and drop feature in the android app that when you drag file from file explorer and drop it in the app, the file will be read and displayed in the app. Without using file picker, only uri from ClipData in OnDragListener.

Is this even possible to make?

When I tryed readin the file like this:

```java
FileInputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
```

it shows me this exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10366 does not have permission to content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/... [user 0]; you could obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

and

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{ecf77b0 23430:com.app.package.name/u0a366} (pid=23430, uid=10366) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

Here is some code for this

```java
dropTarget.setOnDragListener((v, event) -> {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                ...
                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                    if (event.getClipDescription().hasMimeType("application/json")) {
                        ClipData.Item item = event.getClipData().getItemAt(0);
                        readFile(item.getUri());

                    }
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        });
```

```java
void readFile(Uri uri){
            FileInputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            //Reading file
            ...
}
```

Comment: `FileInputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);` That should be `InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);`

Comment: @blackapps still is not working. Throws this exception: `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord{ecf77b0 23430:com.app.package.name/u0a366} (pid=23430, uid=10366) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs`

Comment: Please show value of uri.toString().

Comment: Which file explorer? Try more explorers. Android version of used device?

Comment: @blackapps I tried on two explorers, in android build-in explorer and Goole Files. In android explorer the value for uri.toString() is `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3Adata%2FtestJson%2Farray.json` and for Google Files is `content://com.google.android.apps.nbu.files.provider/2/1000009192`

Comment: I only tried it on Android 13

Comment: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/touch-and-input/drag-drop

Comment: Quote: The target app must call requestDragAndDropPermissions() immediately before handling the data that the user drags into the app.

Comment: Thanks @blackapps, now is working. I tried this solution before and it did not worked. And still now is not working with how I handle reading file but I managed to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [blackapps comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77889821/read-file-from-clipdata-in-ondraglistener#comment137318980_77889821) the issue is that I was not requesting DragAndDrop Permissions. Just needed to add this code in setOnDragListener:

```java
DragAndDropPermissions dropPermissions = null;
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
         dropPermissions = requestDragAndDropPermissions(event);
}

readFile(item.getUri());

if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N && dropPermissions != null) {
         dropPermissions.release();
}
```